# What's wrong with my Symfony deployment on IIS?

Tags: templates, iis, deployment, symfony1, partial

I'm a Symfony newbie and am trying to deploy my application onto an IIS server.

I've followed the steps in http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/symfonyOnIIS but am having no joy. The basics are all set up (I can see the default page at http://playcafe.rcwit.com.au/bookings/index.php).

I can get to the index of my module (http://playcafe.rcwit.com.au/bookings/index.php/booking) but that only shows the layout for the index action. The template isn't showing and the _form.php partial isn't showing either.

I wouldn't be so confused if nothing was working...but why is the layout being hit correctly yet the template and form partial not showing?

Any idea where to start looking?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to clear the cache, and check whether errors are being displayed (try using `trigger_error()` on top of your index.php file). Also, try using the development environement.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have cleared the cache, and using the development environment it's no better but does give an error message: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\inetpub\playcafeBookings\apps\frontend\modules\booking\templates\_form.php on line 504`. (http://playcafe.rcwit.com.au/bookings/frontend_dev.php/booking)

Comment: Oh and by the way, the exact copy of `_form.php` works fine on my dev (apache) environment.

Comment: Strange, you could maybe check this file isn't corrupted, or post it here for us to review it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, turns out this was not *really* an IIS issue. The error I was getting was to do with using short PHP open tags (`<?` as opposed to `<?php`) in a partial, because the config was different in IIS.

Still haven't got other IIS issues fully sorted, but am working through them.